# How can I get indented braces for javascript in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, formatting

Is there a way in visual studio to get braces to indent when editing javascript.

Though there is an option for it in Options under Text Editor:C/C++:Formatting:Indent Braces but for the JScript Text Editor it does not list the 'Indent Braces' as a Formatting option.

How could I accomplish this so that our c++ and js code are consistently formatted? We use whitesmith style for majority of the code

Whitesmith style looks like:

```
if (condition)
    {
    statement();
    }
```

Would there be a way with VS extensions or options to do this?

Any leads/solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do this with Visual Studio. A tool like Resharper can do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2010, go:

`Tools > Options`.
Expand the Text Editor node and select JScript. (a.k.a JavaScript).

Under Formatting, tick the "Place open brace on new line for functions" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

IF you gave up on finding a good tool copy and past you code to http://jsbeautifier.org/ it will take you few  seconds to clean up your javascript mess doing it this way

Answer (score -1):

I like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and agree with Valamas that it allows you to define style of formatting of the code much more fine as Visual Studio. I decide to write my answer because of another problem.

Every language has his standards. Sometimes formatting is not only the matter of taste. JavaScript can **automatically insert of semicolons** in some situations it the code on the next line can be interpret as the separate block statement. For example the line

```js
return
  {
    statement();
  }
```

will be interpret as

```js
return; // return undefined;
  {
    statement();
  }
```

It is the reason why all professional developed JavaScript code use [Kernighan and Ritchie Indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) (K&R style):

```js
return {
    statement();
};
```

It is not important which formatting style you use in *another* language which you mostly use. If you write code in JavaScript I would you strictly recommend to follow K&R style in all parts of your JavaScript code:

```js
if (condition) {
    statement();
}
```

You can read more about semicolon insertion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons) or in 7.9.1 of [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (also [here](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9))

Comment: Thanks we are aware of this and treat return { as  special case